# Have to delete the Bin to see updates with Stride

Tags: stride

I'm using the Stride Game Engine UI to make changes to my game. However, in order to see the updates that I make when I run it I have to delete the Bin folder.

I have tried cleaning the solution, as well as, shutting Stride and Visual Studio down and reopening them but that didn't help, and I needed to delete the Bin to get it to work.

Any ideas what I have setup incorrectly?

Comment: Have you tried the [other methods for clearing cached Stride files](https://doc.stride3d.net/4.0/en/manual/files-and-folders/cached-files.html)? In general, I tend to use `Build` ▶`Clean Solution` for other similar issues w/ VS.

Comment: I have attempted cleaning the solution, Clean -> Rebuild -> Run. This did not help. Added note to my question.